# Page is not responsive to page size change

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have the following code on my web page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/new.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="s" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>

        </div>
        <div style="background-color:white;border-radius:10px;align-content:center;align-self:center;vertical-align:middle;width:1600px;" class="container max-width-940 body-content"  >
                <div style="margin-top: 70px">
       
                <div style="align-items:center; justify-content:left;display:flex;font-size:24px"><b>Recording test testing</b></div>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>
          <span style="font-size:18px"> This is a test1. This is a test2.This is a test3.This is a test4.This is a test5.This is a test6.This is a test7.This is a test8.This is a test9.This is a test10.This is a test11This is a test12This is a test13This is a test14This is a test15This is a test16This is a test17This is a test18This is a test19This is a test20This is a test21This is a test22This is a test23This is a test24.</span>
        </div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
 
   
        
    
           </div>  
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Users are asking me to make this mobile-friendly so whenever I am running the above code, it is not responsive to the mobile application. when I make the page smaller. Instead of "This is test" coming to the next line. It goes beyond the length of the smaller screen. It works fine as a web page, but as soon as I make the screen smaller, the text goes beyond the size of the screen. Below is the screen shot:

[image]

I am using bootstrap in my application and I am also using meta tag on my master page, but it seems the page is not responsive to the size change.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2021? It's been effectively obsolete since 2008.

Comment: width:1600px set for the container which contain "container max-width-940 body-content" make it width:100% it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your containing div with the classes `container max-width-940 body-content` has a series of inline styles added to it.

The inline style `width:1600px;` is preventing the div from becoming any smaller than 1600px. If you remove that attribute from your inline styles the div will resize automatically, as the classes you've added from Bootstrap contain mobile breakpoints:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/new.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="s" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>

        </div>
        <div style="background-color:white;border-radius:10px;align-content:center;align-self:center;vertical-align:middle;" class="container max-width-940 body-content"  >
                <div style="margin-top: 70px">
       
                <div style="align-items:center; justify-content:left;display:flex;font-size:24px"><b>Recording test testing</b></div>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>
          <span style="font-size:18px"> This is a test1. This is a test2.This is a test3.This is a test4.This is a test5.This is a test6.This is a test7.This is a test8.This is a test9.This is a test10.This is a test11This is a test12This is a test13This is a test14This is a test15This is a test16This is a test17This is a test18This is a test19This is a test20This is a test21This is a test22This is a test23This is a test24.</span>
        </div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
 
   
        
    
           </div>  
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```